# how to find the similarity between two documents

Tags: python-3.x, spacy

I have tried using the similarity function of `spacy` to get the best matching sentence in a document. However it fails for bullet points because it considers each bullet as the a sentence and the bullets are incomplete sentences (eg sentence 1 "password should be min 8 characters long , sentence 2 in form of a bullet " 8 characters"). It does not know it is referring to password and so my similarity comes very low.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds to me like you need to do more text processing before attempting to use similarity. If you want bullet points to be considered part of a sentence, you need to modify your spacy pipeline to understand to do so.

Comment: Bullets are considered but the thing is it doesn't understand who 8 characters is referring to so I thought of finding the heading of the paragraph and replacing the bullets with it

I found the headings using python docs but it doesn't read bullets while reading the document ,is there a way I can read it using python docs ?

Is there any way I can find the headings of a paragraph in spacy?

Is there a better approach for it

Answer (score 0):

Bullets are considered but the thing is it doesn't understand  who 8 characters is referring to so I thought of finding the heading of the paragraph  and replacing the bullets with it

I found the headings using python docs but it doesn't read bullets while reading the document  ,is there  a way I can read it using python docs ?

Is there any way I can find the headings of a paragraph  in spacy?

Is there  a better  approach  for it

Answer (score 0):

You can actually modify spaCy's sentencizer to recognize bullet points as sentence boundaries, but an easier way would be to use the [sentence-transformers](https://www.sbert.net/examples/training/sts/README.html) library instead. It doesn't matter if you have bullet points in your sentence in that case.